# GOTO, CONTINUE, BREAK in procedural programming, how do they effect state?

Tags: c, state, control-flow, procedural-programming

In my attempt to gain a better knowledge of procedural programing, both for practical and academic use I am trying to clarify the effect CONTINUE and BREAK statements have on state.

I have come to understand that GOTO is essentially forbidden as I go with the if you're a good programmer you can find a better way approach. However I also understand at a deeper level that it is to be avoided in procedural programming because it lacks the ability to change state.

This is were I get confused, how is it that CONTINUE, and BREAK can change state?

My initial thought was that because a GOTO is as such:

```
GOTO A;
LBL A;
```

No expressions are evaluated and no state is changed. And combined with the form of a CONTINUE:

```
while (evalFunction(*value) == 1) {
  ..
  if ( bail == 1 ) continue;
  ..
}
```

Has the ability to change state in the while condition.

However this does not account for BREAK.

Can someone provide some more detail regarding the specifics in procedural programming?

Comment: How does "continue" change state in the while condition? "break" sort-of changes state in that the condition won't be tested at all, which is sort-of the same as changing the output of the condition--at least if the condition has side-effects. Otherwise no state will be changed other than the loop terminating. I may be misunderstanding what you're asking, though.

Comment: I made an edit to the loop, the continue can cause a change in state by calling the function in the condition. I honestly may just be grasping to something that was meant to be more of a 'here's another one of the many reasons to avoid GOTO'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where this "ability to change state" thing comes from.

The highest virtue of code is readability.  GOTO is to be avoided because it often makes the code *hard to read*, and for no other reason.  There are in fact cases where code that uses GOTO is *easier* to read than it would be if GOTO were avoided, and in those cases, GOTO *should* be used.  A good example is the C nested cleanup idiom:

```
int do_something()
{
   int rv = -1; /* failure */
   Foo *foo = get_a_foo();
   if (!foo) goto out;
   Bar *bar = get_a_bar();
   if (!bar) goto out_foo;

   rv = do_something_with_foo_and_bar(foo, bar);

   release_bar(bar);
out_foo:
   release_foo(foo);
out:
   return rv;
}
```

This is easier to read than the alternative with nested if statements, because normal control flow is emphasized. (In C++ you would use RAII instead, of course, for even less clutter.)

Similarly, BREAK and CONTINUE *can* make the code harder to read, and should be avoided when they do; however, they are in nearly every modern language because they often make code *easier* to read.  So they are *preferred* to complicated if-else constructs inside loops and/or contorting the logic so that the loop exit condition can be tested at the top of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am very familiar with the idea of readability and the GOTO statement. However this doesn't really answer anything regarding BREAK and CONTINUE.

Comment: Also I care about state because it is fundamental to procedural programming, where the goal is to follow instructions to get the desired change in state.

Comment: I suppose you could consider the trajectory of control flow as the evolution of an implicit state variable (the program counter) but I don't think that's a useful thing to do.  Anyway, you appear to be trying to find some analytic basis for what is actually a principle of aesthetics, and I don't think *that*'s a useful thing to do, either.  I meant it when I said "GOTO is to be avoided *for no other reason* than because it often makes code harder to read" (and conversely, BREAK and CONTINUE should be used *for no other reason* than that they often make the code easier to read).